# How to make carousel work properly with php

Tags: php, carousel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGjor.jpg)[Here is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOg7g.jpg) I have tried this code but the carousel is not working properly...The  first image is shown properly but the second one is shown below the first one and not in slides....Here is my code..

```
<div class="banner">
<?php
mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8');
$query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from post_tbl where status='Approved' Order by pid DESC");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
?>
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3><?php echo $row['title']; ?>
                    </h3>
                    <div class="read">
                        <a href="single.html" class="btn btn-primary read-m">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you included the proper JavaScript and CSS?

Comment: yes...it works well when not used php code...

Comment: I'm not all that familiar with carousel, but I'm wondering if you need to move the loop inside of the divs somewhere, so it's only repeating the items and not the whole slider divs.

Comment: I even tried that also...I moved the loop to another div's but same problem

Comment: The carousels need unique ID's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need 2 loops. One to know how many rows you are going to draw. This will be used to build your `ol` DOM.

The second to loop your actual `div` content where your `select` contains the necessary information.

```
 <div class="banner">
    <?php
    mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8');
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from post_tbl where status='Approved' Order by pid DESC");
    ?>
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <?php for ($numElements = 0; $numElements < mysqli_num_rows($query); $numElements++) : ?>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
                data-slide-to="<?php echo $numElements ?>" <?php echo($numElements == 0 ? 'class="active"' : '') ?> ></li>
        <?php endfor; ?>

        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <?php $rows = mysqli_fetch_array($query); ?>
            <?php foreach ($rows as $row) : ?>
                <div class="carousel-item <?php echo($row == reset($rows) ? 'active' : '') ?>">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3><?php echo $row['title']; ?>
                        </h3>
                        <div class="read">
                            <a href="single.html" class="btn btn-primary read-m">Read More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This should set your DOM correctly.

If you are already familiar with OOP concepts this gets way more organised and protected and would highly advice to follow that route instead.

Also there are plenty of threads around warning about **sql injection** so, if you are thinking on having a variable to dynamically adjust your query, please look into those first

As an introduction I can leave you with [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

Comment: it gives me this error - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS) in <li> tag

Comment: And with reason. Needed to wrap `class` around `\``. Edited the code to fix that

Comment: Now, the slides disappeared...the whole <div> disappeared

Comment: If you inspect the element, until when does it process? Also, have you closed the last div? I only added the changes for internal div but didnt close the outside div that wraps it all up which means you still need to add the `<a>` elements and the last `<div>`

Comment: can u please do the whole php thing...I am not getting anythin...please help me..

Comment: @DebrazG let me encapsulate your entire code then and then try and copy it all

Comment: @DebrazG added the entirety of your banner with the changes

Comment: @DebrazG we need to carry this dicussion on a room. Do you mind accessing [this room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196821/answer-debate)?

Comment: ufff, right, from what I can see from your picture your are looping outside the answer as well. The very fact your got the `<a>` tags repeated 4 times assert that. Remove whatever code you have and leave it only to the answer and the DB connection and try it out. I don't see any logic in my answer that would actually trigger what you just showed me

Comment: can i mail my whole script to you?

Comment: I have sent that whole page...if u want any other pages please ask me....and thanks for helping me..